# Using Longitude/Latitude as Waypoint

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the longitude latitude as a waypoint in my google maps and cant seem to get it working.

Here's how I have my values pushed

```
waypts_mtlsheloc.push({
    location: (45.658197,-73.636333), //I don't think I'm supposed to write this like that. But can't find the right way.
    stopover: true
})
```

And then try to modify my line like this

```
service.route({
    origin: latlng_mtlsheloc[0],
    destination: latlng_mtlsheloc[latlng_mtlsheloc.length - 1],
    waypoints:waypts_mtlsheloc,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
}, function(result, status) {
        console.log(status)
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        path = path.concat(result.routes[0].overview_path);
        line_mtlsheloc.setPath(result.routes[0].overview_path);
    }
});
```

But it gives me an error "Error in property [waypoint]", I've tried different methods of writing down the location, but can't seem to find the right one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To use a latitude and longitude as a waypoint, it must be a google.maps.LatLng object
(the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsWaypoint) says a string or a LatLng; string is an address, LatLng is geographic coordinates)

```
waypts_mtlsheloc.push({
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(45.658197,-73.636333),
    stopover: true
})
```

[Working Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypointsC.html)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/npvsfz0d/497/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {

  var request = {
    origin: "1521 NW 54th St, Seattle, WA 98107 ",
    destination: "San Diego, CA",
    waypoints: [{
      location: new google.maps.LatLng(42.496403, -124.413128),
      stopover: false
    }],
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
      summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
      // For each route, display summary information.
      for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
      }
    } else {
      alert("directions response " + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
<div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
  <div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
</div>
```